# Changes needed to make this code book tickets in numerical order rather than random?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, random, numerical

**I would like the code to print out in numerical order rather than a random integer as it does at present due to the fact that I now want to fill up the bookings from 1 to the upper range of 32. Any help on this would be really appreciated, thanks in advance.

sorry if my English isn't the greatest it is not my first language!**

```
 class FirstClassCompartment
 { 
        public void FirstClassTickets()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            bool[] seats = new bool[32];
            List<int> seatsBooked = new List<int>();
            int completeBooking = 0;
            bool quit = false;
            string ticketAmount = "";
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to the First Class booking menu");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of tickets you would like to book");
                ticketAmount = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("\nFirst Class booking menu");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Please press 1 to complete your first class booking");
                completeBooking = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                switch (completeBooking)
                {
                    case 1:
                        int firstClassSeat;
                        if (seatsBooked.Count == 0)
                        {
                            firstClassSeat = rand.Next(32);
                            seats[firstClassSeat] = true;
                            seatsBooked.Add(firstClassSeat);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            do
                            {
                                firstClassSeat = rand.Next(32);
                                if (!seatsBooked.Contains(firstClassSeat))
                                {
                                    seats[firstClassSeat] = true;

                                }
                            }
                            while (seatsBooked.Contains(firstClassSeat) && seatsBooked.Count < 32);
                            if (seatsBooked.Count < 32)
                            {
                                seatsBooked.Add(firstClassSeat);
                            }
                        }
                        if (seatsBooked.Count >= 32)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("All seats for first class have been booked");
                            Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to continue...");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your seat: {0}", firstClassSeat + 1);
                            Console.WriteLine("Please press enter to continue...");

                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: INVALID SELECTION");
                        quit = true;
                        break;
                }
            } while (!quit);
        }
    }
}
```

**strong text**

Comment: are you familiar with how to use the debugger..? if you wrote this code I don't see what the issue is.. please explain what the code is doing now and where the issue is happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put `int firstClassSeat=0` before the do{} while() loop instead of in the switch() statement. Then, instead of `firstClassSeat=rand.Next(32);` simply do `firstClassSeat++;`

Comment: You are a life saver! This works, thank you